# piezoelectricity

Tags: piezoelectricity, piezo, piezoelectric-effect

By knowing some of the features of piezoelectric sensor, I want to know more about this sensor. how does it actually works? Does it require application of pressure and releasing that pressure often to generate electricity? Or can a constant pressure on that sensor generates electricity? 
 I want to know where these sensors are actually used?  are there any disadvantages ?  Will it really helps in power optimization?

Comment: There's tons of information on piezoelectric sensors on the internet.  Hit google, read up a bit, come back with specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how does it actually works?

Squeezing the crystal causes some atoms to go up and some to go down, pushing electrons to one surface.

> Does it require application of pressure and releasing that pressure often to generate electricity?

To generate electrical *energy*, yes, and you have to put that through a rectifier to capture it.  ("Electricity" is a vague term.)

> Or can a constant pressure on that sensor generates electricity?

No.  Applying constant pressure produces a charge imbalance, which then slowly dissipates through the leakage resistance of the crystal.

> I want to know where these sensors are actually used?

Anywhere you want to measure pressure.

> are there any disadvantages ?

Yes.  They are brittle, have very high output impedance, etc.